# Combine all the kill bash command in one line

Tags: python, django, bash, kill, kill-process

I am using the following command to kill my servers at the moment and want to combine them into one.

```
1- ps aux | grep 'python manage.py runserver' 
   sudo kill -9 $PID
2- ps aux | grep 'python -m SimpleHTTPServer'
   sudo kill -9 $PID
3- ps aux | grep 'aptly api server'
   sudo kill -9 $PID
```

Is there a way to kill all the three processes using a single command? or atleast combine them.

EDIT: I am trying the below command but it is just print out single PID number. [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ps aux | egrep -i 'python manage.py runserver|aptly api serve|python -m SimpleHTTPServer' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
```

Comment: Why it is only printing out one a single PID ? `rakesh@r:~$ ps aux | grep 'python manage.py runserver | python -m SimpleHTTPServer | aptly api server' | awk '{print $2}'
3698`

Comment: Possibly because I inserted spaces in the regex where I shouldn't have. Try it now.

Comment: Nothing cnanges. `rakesh@r:~$ ps aux | grep 'python manage.py runserver|python -m SimpleHTTPServer|aptly api server' | awk '{print $2}'
3775`

Comment: Ah, I think it was also just picking up the `grep` process itself and not working because `|` by default isn't recognized by `grep` as a regex special char. Try now.

Comment: What does `ps aux | grep 'python\|aptly'` get you? What about `ps aux | egrep 'python|aptly'`?

Comment: `ps aux | grep 'python\|aptly` --> `rakesh@r:~$ ps aux | grep 'python manage.py\|aplty api serve'
rakesh    4053  0.3  0.7  75088 28476 pts/4    S+   22:17   0:00 python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
rakesh    4067  2.0  0.8 151856 30628 pts/4    Sl+  22:17   0:01 /opt/moorgate/bin/python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
rakesh    4086  0.0  0.0  15944  2232 pts/11   S+   22:18   0:00 grep --color=auto python manage.py\|aplty api serve`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91993/discussion-between-alex-hall-and-rakesh-ranjan-sukla).

Comment: `ps aux | egrep -i 'python manage.py runserver|aptly api serve|python -m SimpleHTTPServer'` this one gives out all the server name